# How to adjust the width of the NgbModal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I am trying to adjust the width of the NgbModal to 80vw but it is not showing. Am I missing something or? I even went through the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api) but is doesn't show how to add custom sizing.

Here's my piece of code below:

```
.modal-content { width: 80vw; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see height is changing. check attached screenshot.
[image]